# how to write unix grep filesystem equivalent to windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How to write below unix command in windows batch file. please help on this.

My requirement is currently the free space check shell script need to convert to windows batch script.

My shell script is as below which will check the free space under projects folder.

The script executed from tmp folder and it will give staus "1" or "0"

```
 cd /tmp
 freeSpace=`df /projects | grep -v 'Filesystem' |awk '{ print $4}'|sed 's/%//'`
  if [ ${freeSpace} -ge 85 ];then
echo "1" 
  else
echo "0" 
 fi
```

Thanks

Comment: My unix is rusty; what does the output of this look like?

Comment: freeSpace=`df /projects | grep -v 'Filesystem' |awk '{ print $4}'|sed 's/%//'`   if [ ${freeSpace} -ge 85 ];then
    echo "1" 
else
 echo "0" 
fi  output should be 0 or 1

Comment: There are Windows ports of `GREP` and `AWK` and many other old unix based command.

Comment: @testprabhu Don't do that.  Edit your question and post the expected output.

Comment: @testprabhu - You will get more traction on SO if you post something (anything) you have written. I've heard many times that SO is not a code writing (or porting) service. Are you permitted to use Powershell in your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, begin your batch script with

```
@echo off
setlocal
```

... to prevent displaying the executing commands, and to limit the scope of variables to this running script.

Next, to capture the output of a command, use `for /f`.  See `help for` in a cmd console for more information.

There are a few ways to check the free space of a hard drive in Windows.  One is to perform a wmi query using `wmic.exe`.  Here's an example that captures the free space to a variable:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%I in ('wmic logicaldisk where "name='c:'" get freespace^,size /format:csv') do set "freespace=%%I"
echo %freespace%
```

Capturing from `wmic` is tricky, as WMI data is encoded in UCS-2 Little Endian if I recall correctly.  It screws with the console.  That's why the query includes "size" as a throwaway value.

Another less-fiddly way to get free space is to capture the output from `dir` like this:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%I in ('dir ^| find /i "bytes free"') do set "freespace=%%I"
set "freespace=%freespace:,=%"
echo %freespace%
```

In the second example, the number contains commas, which makes integer comparisons impossible without stripping those commas.  That's what the `%freespace:,=%` does -- it performs substring substitutions, replacing `,` with nothing.  [See this page](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) for more string manipulation tricks.

Either way, to compare the size, do this:

```
if %freespace% gtr 85 (
    echo 1
) else (
    echo 0
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

The trick in `Windows` is having all the utilities you use available.  You use `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, and `df`.  All of these tools, except for `awk`, are available in [UnxUtils for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/), a free & open source set of unix-like programs compiled for Windows.

Download `UnxUtils` and decompress it somewhere convenient (like c:\unxutils) and then add the location of its bin files to the system `PATH` environment variable so that they can be used on the command line & in scripts.  The binary location is `%unxutilsbase%\usr\local\wbin`.

For `awk`, you can use [Gawk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm).  Installation instructions are similar and are [detailed here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/install.html).

Once they're installed, you should be able to write your Windows script file almost exactly as you have

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation